# How to command grep not to display the searched string?

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep

I want to print a part of a line in a file. The whole line looks like this.

```
Path=fy2tbaj8.default-1404984419419
```

I want to print only the characters after `Path=`. I have tried `grep Path filename | head -5`. But its not working.It still shows the entire line. How can i do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use `cut` command for this purpose.

```
grep Path filename |cut -c6-
```

Here `-c6-` option means print from 6th to last character.

Answer (score 43):

You can use `grep` and just `grep`:

```
grep -oP "(?<=Path=).*" file
```

[image]

**Explanation**:

From `man grep`:

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)
```

The [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=Path=)` asserts that at the current position in the string, what precedes is the characters `Path=`. If the assertion succeeds, the engine matches the resolution pattern.

For Perl 5 regular expression syntax, read the [Perl regular expressions man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: This helped. For me, what was best was `grep -orn . -e 'myQuery'` (to search the current directory recursively for a string and show the line number where matches were found).

Comment: Actually `grep -orn ".\{0,10\}myQuery.\{0,10\}" .` was even better because it shows context around the matches. https://superuser.com/a/1005747/74576

Answer (score 9):

The `awk` solution is what I would use, but a slightly smaller process to launch is `sed` and it can produce the same results, but by substituting the PATH= part of the line with `""` , i.e.

```
  sed -n 's/^Path=//p' file
```

The `-n` overrides `sed`s default behavior of 'print all lines' (so `-n` = no print), 
and to print a line, we add the `p` character after the substition. Only lines where the substitution happens will be printed.

This gives you the behavior you have asked for, of `grep`ing for a string, but removing the `Path=` part of the line.

If, per David Foerster's comments, you have a large file and wish to stop processing as soon as you have matched and printed the first match to 'Path=', you can tell sed to quit, with the `q` command. Note that you need to make it a command-group by surrounding both in `{ ..}` and separating each command with a `;`. So the enhanced command is

```
sed -n 's/^Path=//{p;q;}` file
```

IHTH

Comment: Make that `s/^Path=//p` since we only want to match at the beginning of a line. We can match only the first occurrence with `s/^Path=//{p;q}`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster :   Thanks, for those improvements, I'm adding them to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU grep:

```
$ echo Path=fy2tbaj8.default-1404984419419 | grep -oP '(Path=)\K.*'
fy2tbaj8.default-1404984419419
```

`\K` keeps the stuff left of the \K, don't include it in `$&`.

Comment: It would be better if you include this one `'(Path=)\K.*'` according to the OP is supposed. I also was looking this command. `\K` is nice option. thanks. upvoted

Comment: @KasiyA: Updated. Feel free to edit anything you think make the answer better.

Comment: @KasiyA why the parentheses? They don't do anything useful there, this does the same thing: `grep -oP 'Path=\K.*'`

Comment: @terdon: As I guess, he want to emphasis the part that OP don't want.

Answer (score 5):

`grep` greps a line of text and displays it. `head` displays the first *n* lines of text, not characters.

You're looking for `sed` or `awk`:

```
awk '{print $2}' FS='='
```

This sets `=` as a field separator and prints the second field.

Comment: Is it not even better to use `FS='PATH='`?

Comment: You can do awk as a "one liner" `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "=" } ; /pattern/ {print $2}' file_to_search`

Comment: @don.joey: I'd use `FS='='` so you can use the `$1` ("PATH") when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the solution is to use `grep -Po`.

Let's add some other solutions, for completeness:

- with `cut`, setting the delimiter the `=`:

  ```
  cut -d'=' -f2 file
  ```
- It might be a bit risky, but you can also [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) the file, so that `$Path` will contain the value.

  ```
  source file
  echo "$Path"
  ```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
this=aaabbccc
that=dddeee
$ source a
$ echo "$this"
aaabbccc
$ echo "$that"
dddeee
```

---

As per comments, see how to `source` just part of the file:

```
$ cat a
Path=22
Path=33
$ source a
$ echo $Path
33
$ source <(head -1 a)
$ echo $Path
22
```

Comment: If file contains more lines that starts with `Path=` then what is your solution? it just return last one of them.

Comment: That's out of the scope of the question, as the OP is supposed to know where in the file are these lines. However, you can play around with `source` and `head`/`tail`. For example, `source <(head -3 file)` to just get the 3 first lines of the file, etc.

Comment: Still returns last one

Comment: @KasiyA of course it returns the last one, that's why I suggest using `head`/`tail` to get the block of code in which it is unique.

Comment: I said still returns last one also with using `head/tail`

Comment: @KasiyA did you check what you comment? See my update showing the real behaviour.

Comment: Again did you check with `source <(head -2 test)` to get the 2 first lines?

Comment: @KasiyA try to read my comments, because we agree: of course if you source two lines with the same variable, it will store the last one. I said it many comments ago :D

Comment: You said "`source <(head -3 file)` to just get the **3 first lines** of the file" AND didn't say it returns 3rd line, as far as I know! Then your second solution is not true.

Comment: @KasiyA I assume if you use this site is because you can see a little bit through the comments and understand what I mean. It is obvious I meant that that command would source the 3 first lines of the file. Also, I will remove all these comments in a while as do not add any value to the answer.

Comment: And my point is about when you have 2 lines with same variable in a file and when you run `echo $Path` I except you, your solution return back both 2 lines in result not last one. right?

Comment: @KasiyA check the update I mentioned 23425t2 comments above.

Comment: What do you mean about <23425t2>?