# How can I output a single word in the terminal

Tags: command-line

The title doesn't give the question justice. I'm writing a shell script, for use in conky, to get the status of my mouse and keyboard's battery. Previously, I used `upower` to do this:

```
dev=`upower -e | grep "mouse_"`
upower -i $dev | grep 'state' | cut '-c26-36'
```

As you can see, I used the `cut` command to trim the result as it's position never changed.

However, today I found a bug in upower. It cannot see my mouse being charged. So, I have installed solaar from github which does display the correct status. But I'm not sure how to trim the result:

```
solaar show mouse | grep 'Battery'
# outputs "Battery: N/A, recharging."
```

I cannot use `cut` anymore because the segment 'N/A' has an arbitrary length.

Ideally, I'd like the script to output any word which follows the first comma.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to command grep not to display the searched string?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530141/how-to-command-grep-not-to-display-the-searched-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a single `grep`:

```
solaar show mouse | grep -oP 'Battery.*, \K.*'
```

Comment: Will this fail if more than one line has a comma?

Comment: @Waldermort, it will output what's after the comma for the lines containing a comma. To restrict to Battery tough, you can use  `grep -oP 'Battery.*, \K.*'`, I've updated my answer to support this

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
solaar show mouse | grep 'Battery' | sed -r 's/^.*, //'
```

`^`: delimiter, matches the start of the string; `.`: matches any character; `*`: matches any number of occurencies (including `0`) of the previous character; `,`: matches `,`; : matches